# disable KMP_AFFINITY for AMD ryzen

Tags: c#, windows, environment-variables, intel, amd-processor

I'm trying out some of the prebuilt sample programs for Flir IR cameras with Atlas SDK7.
When I run one of them I get this message in a command window;

OMP: Warning #72: KMP_AFFINITY: affinity only supported for Intel(R) processors.

OMP: Warning #71: KMP_AFFINITY: affinity not supported, using "disabled
When I close the window, the entire application closes.

I found the following solution to disable KMP_AFFINITY in Windows (I have a Ryzen CPU)
Go to control panel>system>advanced systems settings>environment variables>
Create a new system variable
Name = KMP_AFFINITY
Variable value = disabled
This works, but I'm not sure what all this is about and what the best practice is.

Obviously I want to avoid this kind of errors in my own code.
Can I disable KMP_AFFINITY in my source code? (using visual studio C#)
Or do I only get this error because the sample was built on an Intel machine?
When I build the sample myself, it looks like I don't get this error?